# normalize 2 result data json table

Tags: php, arrays, json, symfony4

I use json-decode to transform my data to json table ,
my problem is that i have 2 results json table and i try to normalized to get a single result in standardized format, is there any idea how i normalize my data

**resut 1**

"PEAR.Commenting.ClassComment.MissingCategoryTag",
                    "severity": 5,
                    "type": "ERROR",
                    "line": 14,
                    "column": 2,
                    "fixable": false
                },

```
{
    "endPosition": { "character": 63, "line": 69, "position": 1565 },
    "failure": "comment must start with a space",
    "name": "/home/ke/Front-Analyse/e2e/src/account/register/register.po.ts",
    "ruleName": "comment-format",
    "ruleSeverity": "ERROR",
    "startPosition": { "character": 10, "line": 69, "position": 1512 }
},
{
    "endPosition": { "character": 15, "line": 10, "position": 388 },
    "failure": "Identifier 'newUser' is never reassigned; use 'const' instead of 'let'.",
    "fix": { "innerStart": 377, "innerLength": 3, "innerText": "const" },
    "name": "/home/ke/Front-Analyse/e2e/src/account/register/register.e2e-spec.ts",
    "ruleName": "prefer-const",
    "ruleSeverity": "ERROR",
    "startPosition": { "character": 8, "line": 10, "position": 381 }
},
{
    "endPosition": { "character": 20, "line": 19, "position": 610 },
    "failure": "Identifier 'existantUser' is never reassigned; use 'const' instead of 'let'.",
    "fix": { "innerStart": 594, "innerLength": 3, "innerText": "const" },
    "name": "/home/ke/Front-Analyse/e2e/src/account/register/register.e2e-spec.ts",
    "ruleName": "prefer-const",
    "ruleSeverity": "ERROR",
    "startPosition": { "character": 8, "line": 19, "position": 598 }
},
```

**result 2**

```
    "filePath": "/home/ke/NODEEE/app.js",
    "messages": [
        {
            "ruleId": "no-undef",
            "severity": 2,
            "message": "'require' is not defined.",
            "line": 1,
            "column": 19,
            "nodeType": "Identifier",
            "messageId": "undef",
            "endLine": 1,
            "endColumn": 26
        },
        {
            "ruleId": "no-undef",
            "severity": 2,
            "message": "'require' is not defined.",
            "line": 2,
            "column": 15,
            "nodeType": "Identifier",
            "messageId": "undef",
            "endLine": 2,
            "endColumn": 22
        },
        {
            "ruleId": "no-undef",
            "severity": 2,
            "message": "'require' is not defined.",
            "line": 3,
            "column": 12,
            "nodeType": "Identifier",
            "messageId": "undef",
            "endLine": 3,
            "endColumn": 19
        },

Array
```

(
    [totals] => Array
        (
            [errors] => 2
            [warnings] => 0
            [fixable] => 0
        )

```
[files] => Array
    (
        [/home/ke/Test-Code/CODE.php] => Array
            (
                [errors] => 2
                [warnings] => 0
                [messages] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [message] => Missing file doc comment
                                [source] => PEAR.Commenting.FileComment.Missing
                                [severity] => 5
                                [type] => ERROR
                                [line] => 2
                                [column] => 1
                                [fixable] => 
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [message] => Expected "for (...) {\n"; found "for (...)\n{\n"
                                [source] => PEAR.ControlStructures.ControlSignature.Found
                                [severity] => 5
                                [type] => ERROR
                                [line] => 12
                                [column] => 1
                                [fixable] => 
                            )

                    )

            )

    )
```

)

Comment: show your code. Neither result1 nor result 2 is valid json as posted, so json_decode is going to complain somehow. ALso show how/where you got these non-json strings.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg I edited my post and I added the result json_decode